# Angular-highcharts pushing data from api into highchart option

Tags: angular, highcharts

I got following data (https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json):

```
{
   bpi: {
   2017-12-15: 17601.9438,
   2017-12-16: 19343.04,
   2017-12-17: 19086.6438,
   2017-12-18: 18960.5225,
   ...
}
```

I use this library to visualize my line chart: https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts

I tried to push the above data into the highcharts option, but nothing showed up without any errors. Therefore, I doubt my pushing method that needs someone give advice.

Here is the code:

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  stockChart: StockChart;
  historyData = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.apiService.getBtcData()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.historyData = Object.values(data.bpi);
      console.log(this.historyData);
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stockChart = new StockChart({
       series: [{
          tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
          },
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          name: 'BTC/USD',
          data: this.historyData
        }]
    }) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`historyData` is not defined when you are initializing the chart data in your ngOnInit, so your chart has no data. You should instead initialize your chart within your subscribe (after historyData is defined)

```
this.apiService.getBtcData()
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.historyData = Object.values(data.bpi);

        this.stockChart = new StockChart(...);
    });
```

or set the data through the highcharts [setData](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) method and redraw the chart

```
this.apiService.getBtcData()
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.historyData = Object.values(data.bpi);
        // assign chart data and redraw (2nd parameter of setData)
        this.stockChart.ref.series[0].setData(this.historyData, true);
    });
```

Comment: It's true, I will try again. Thank you